# Clear stdout in C?

Tags: c, stdout

Is there any way to clear the standard output buffer in C?

I have a program in which I don't know if I am going to output data until the end of a loop.

I would like to have my logic be something like:

```
printf("data1\n");
printf("data2\n");

...

if (printTuple)
    fflush(stdout); //Print the data to stdout
else
    /*Clear stdout*/ //Clear stdout
```

I have tried `memset(stdout, 0, sizeof(stdout))` and `rewind(stdout)`, neither of which work.

Comment: `printTuple == TRUE` :facepalm:

Comment: create a local buffer and then output it all at once if you need to?

Comment: @Kevin not my choice. It's for a project, and it has to be explicit. I know that's awful to do :)

Comment: @clcto, the buffer was my backup idea, make a dynamic string that grows as I read data & allocate more space when necessary. I didn't know if there was a possibility of avoiding it.

Comment: It's not just awful, it's incorrect. If `printTuple` is, say, 2, it is true but not `== TRUE`, so it will not be printed as it should. Whoever told you it has to be explicit should be fired.

Comment: printTuple is a char with values TRUE (1) and FALSE (0), where `TRUE` and `FALSE` are `#define` constants.

Comment: Yes, that's a fairly standard definition. But 0 and 1 are not the only possible values in a `char` - they are 0-255 or -128-+127, depending on your compiler and options.

Comment: *sigh*...Kevin I understand that. It's a quick 2-week school project. I'm not concerned with the values being out of expected range.

Comment: Yes, but someone forced this *interesting* rule on you, so please give them our greetings, and tell them that they really should not enforce such a rule. I was on the verge of commenting on that as well, but Kevin beat me to it...

Comment: Sam, you are `fflush`'ing your `stdout` to print whatever in it, does this mean that you've made your `stdout` to be buffered, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing stdout is not an option.  Instead, you just have to avoid printing anything to stdout until after you've determined whether that's what you want to do.  If your program is simple enough, this could be accomplished by just relocating the `printf` statements.  For more complex programs, you'll need some intermediate storage of what you'll be printing (either the values to print or an internal buffer of the actual strings).

Comment: Hi @jwodder, why can't you use ```system("clear")```

Comment: @HarryDuffy: That clears the entire screen, not just the program's output.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to reliably retract what has been committed to `printf()` and friends. However, you can use `open_memstream()` to your advantage: It gives you a `FILE*` to which you can `fprintf()` anything you want in the normal way. However, once you close the `FILE*` created with `open_memstream()`, you get a malloc'd buffer *with the entire text you printed to the file pointer*.

Usage is as follows:

```
char* buffer = NULL;
size_t bufferSize = 0;
FILE* myStream = open_memstream(&buffer, &bufferSize);

fprintf(myStream, "You can output anything to myStream, just as you can with stdout.\n");
myComplexPrintFunction(myStream);    //Append something of completely unknown size.

fclose(myStream);    //This will set buffer and bufferSize.
printf("I can do anything with the resulting string now. It is: \"%s\"\n", buffer);
free(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use [__fpurge](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge), and on some Unices (BSD, Solaris, *et al*) you can use [fpurge](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge), but this is not portable to other platforms, such as Windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio_ext.h>

if (printTuple)
    fflush(stdout);   // Print the data to stdout
else
    __fpurge(stdout); // Clear stdout
```

As others have already noted, your whole approach is fraught with potential problems and you should really re-think your design.

Answer (score 2):

In linux you can use `'\033c'` code for cleaning stdout
example:  `fputs("\033c", stdout);`

Comment: That doesn't clear the process stdout; it is a terminal control sequence that the terminal reads from your program stdout and clears the window.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get an answer to my comment, but I think since you are using `fflush` to print, you seem to have your `stdout` buffered.

In that case, you must have allocated some memory as a buffer as well. That buffer should have been the memory you should be setting to `0`, like `memset( stdout->_base, 0, stdout->_bufsiz )`, but that wouldn't do the job either.

Anyway, the following line would do, what I think you'd like to have, provided that your situation is how I think it is:

```
    stdout->_ptr = stdout->_base;
```

Yeah, simple as that.

I have no idea whether this is undefined behaviour or not; it is just something that I had found out while I was examining the `FILE` structure a while ago.